# When will Salesforce migrate away from Adobe Flash?

Tags: visual-workflow, content-delivery, flash

Salesforce uses Adobe Flash among other things for content delivery and visual workflows. Flash is being phased out by the major browsers. Does anyone know if/when Salesforce will migrate away from Flash?

I just asked Salesforce support and heard that: "Our product team is working on migrating from Flash to SVG technology"

Also on the subject of when: "As I have checked internal discussions by the Product team some final discussion is yet to be made by the Team to finally provide any ETA on this."

If anyone has more specific information than i'd love to heard it!

Ps: Existing idea exchange request for this: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000oMQqAAM

Comment: I'd love to find this out too, as I like Flow but really get annoyed with having to use Flash to do it. I suspect until it gets into the release previews we won't know and I doubt engineering will even hint at a date till it is likely to be coming in the next release.

Comment: That does sound like Salesforce's way of doing things. Let's hope someone has maybe heard something of the record and is willing to help.

Answer (score 1):

Flash in content deliveries will be replaced with html in the summer '17 release according to the files chatter group. (Safe harbor applies of course.)

Comment: reference link would be appreciated =)

Comment: @glls Sorry, I should have included that back then. However, this is live these days for Lightning orgs so I guess it doesn't require a reference anymore. If you want it however, I'll try to find it for you?